# How to create cross frequency/proportion table for variables in R (see example below)?

Tags: r

Sorry for maybe the basic question. I am trying to build a proportional table for categorical variables where the column and rows represent the same variables and that each cell of the table represents the frequency of the row variable (variables are not mutually exclusive) within instances with the column variables.
Example in the table below (but for a bigger dataset of course)

Sample code and small tibble(I am using tidy verse) -- sorry cannot use the real data

```
 sample_data <- read_csv("var A, var B, var C, var D
                    y, y, y, n
                    y,n,n,y
                    y,n,n,n
                    n,n,y,y
                    n,y,n,y
                    n,y,n,y
                    y,n,y,n")
```

I then use this code manually for each variable, the issue is that I have a lot of variables and data point and I wanted to know if there is a way to avoid doing it manually

```
sample_data%>% group_by(`var A`, `var B`) %>% summarise(count = n()) %>% mutate(prop = count/sum(count))
```

The table below is the result when I do it manually

|  | Var A | Var B | Var C | Var D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Var A |  | 33% | 66% | 25% |
| Var B | 25% |  | 33% | 50% |
| Var C | 50% | 33% |  | 25% |
| Var D | 25% | 66% | 33% |  |

Thanks a lot and sorry for the silly question I am just starting out with R

Comment: see `?table`, `?prop.table` ...

Comment: You need to provide some sample data. What are the categories within Var A, etc? Or are Var A, etc the categories within a single variable? Or are Var A, etc presence/absence data? Provide some data and show us how you came up with the table.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Since, your variables overlap and row% or col% != 100%, a small reproducible example to depict this stated overlap, is required.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I edited the qs with example, sorry it is just my first time posting a qs.

Answer (score 0):

Working just with matrices in base R:

```
> set.seed(1)
> mat <- matrix(sample(c(FALSE, TRUE), 100, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10)
> mat

       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
 [1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [5,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 [6,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
 [7,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [8,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [9,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[10,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

> simplify2array(lapply(1:ncol(mat), function(x) colMeans(mat[mat[, x], , drop = FALSE])))

           [,1] [,2]      [,3] [,4]  [,5]      [,6] [,7] [,8]      [,9]     [,10]
 [1,] 1.0000000  0.6 0.6666667  0.6 0.500 0.6666667 0.25  0.6 0.3333333 0.6666667
 [2,] 0.5000000  1.0 0.3333333  0.4 0.375 0.3333333 0.75  0.4 0.6666667 0.5000000
 [3,] 0.3333333  0.2 1.0000000  0.2 0.375 0.3333333 0.25  0.2 0.0000000 0.3333333
 [4,] 0.5000000  0.4 0.3333333  1.0 0.500 0.6666667 0.25  0.8 1.0000000 0.5000000
 [5,] 0.6666667  0.6 1.0000000  0.8 1.000 0.6666667 0.75  0.8 0.6666667 1.0000000
 [6,] 0.3333333  0.2 0.3333333  0.4 0.250 1.0000000 0.25  0.4 0.3333333 0.1666667
 [7,] 0.1666667  0.6 0.3333333  0.2 0.375 0.3333333 1.00  0.2 0.3333333 0.3333333
 [8,] 0.5000000  0.4 0.3333333  0.8 0.500 0.6666667 0.25  1.0 0.6666667 0.5000000
 [9,] 0.1666667  0.4 0.0000000  0.6 0.250 0.3333333 0.25  0.4 1.0000000 0.1666667
[10,] 0.6666667  0.6 0.6666667  0.6 0.750 0.3333333 0.50  0.6 0.3333333 1.0000000
```